# Defining geodesics in differential geometry and reparametrizing

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, geodesic, connections

In a differential geometry course we were given the following two definitions of a geodesic on a manifold $M$ with $TM$ the tangent bundle on $M$:

Definition 1:
Let $V \in \Gamma(\gamma, TM)$ for an unparameterized geodesic $\gamma$. Then $\exists$ $\lambda: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $V^a \nabla_a V^b = \lambda V^b$

Definition 2:
Let $V \in \Gamma(\alpha, TM)$ for a parameterized geodesic $\alpha$, then $V^a \nabla_a V^b$ = 0

I expect these are compatible but I am having trouble showing it.

Comment: I have trouble in understanding your notations $\Gamma(\gamma,TM),\Gamma(\alpha,TM)$. Anyway what happens if you insert $\alpha(t):=\gamma(s(t))$ for some function $s=s(t)$? Can you make $\lambda$ vanish for a suitable $s$?

Comment: To my understanding, $\gamma$ at this point is simply a 1-dimensional submanifold of $M$, so I'm not sure what sense it makes to even plugin $s(t)$ to it. I'm thinking you might define a coordinate patch $t$ on $\gamma$ just as you would define coordinates $x = (x^1, ..., x^n)$ in a coordinate patch on $M$. Then a parametrization $\alpha: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ would simply be the glue required to make it sensible to write down $x(t)$ i.e. $x = \alpha$. From there a reparameterization would be a different $\tilde t$ but I'm not seeing how that's going to make anything vanish.

Comment: $\Gamma(\gamma, TM)$ meaning sections $\gamma \rightarrow TM$ for a curve $\gamma$ on $M$

Comment: Should $V$ be tangent to $\gamma$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation corresponding to an unparametrized geodesic $\gamma=\gamma(t)$ (if you want to think of $\gamma$ as a 1-dimensional manidold, then $t$ is just any local coordinate on $\gamma$) is (your Def.1, $\gamma=(\gamma^1,...,\gamma^d)$ in local coordinates on the $d$-dimensional manifold $M$)
$$
\frac{d^2\gamma^i}{dt^2}(t)+\Gamma_{jk}^i(\gamma(t))\frac{d\gamma^j}{dt}(t)\frac{d\gamma^k}{dt}(t)=\lambda(t)\frac{d\gamma^i}{dt}(t),\qquad i=1,...,d.
$$
Here and below we use Einstein's convention on contracted indices.

Now let $t=t(s)$ and $\alpha^i(s)=\gamma^i(t(s))$ for an yet unspecified change of parametrization between $t,s$. By the chain rule (denoting for simplicity $\frac{dt}{ds}=\frac{dt}{ds}(s)$ and $\frac{d^2t}{ds^2}=\frac{d^2t}{ds^2}(s)$)
$$
\frac{d\alpha^i}{ds}(s)=\frac{dt}{ds}\frac{d\gamma^i}{dt}(t(s)),
\qquad
\frac{d^2\alpha^i}{ds^2}(s)=\left(\frac{dt}{ds}\right)^2\frac{d^2\gamma^i}{dt^2}(t(s))+\frac{d^2t}{ds^2}\frac{d\gamma^i}{dt}(t(s)).
$$
Plugging this into the first equation (multiplied by $(dt/ds)^2$ and evaluated at $t=t(s)$) you get
$$
\frac{d^2\alpha^i}{ds^2}(s)+\Gamma_{jk}^i(\alpha(s))\frac{d\alpha^j}{ds}(s)\frac{d\alpha^k}{ds}(s)=\left(\lambda(t(s))\left(\frac{dt}{ds}\right)^2+\frac{d^2t}{ds^2}\right)\frac{d\gamma^i}{dt}(t(s)),
$$
and you can now choose appropriately $t=t(s)$ to make the RHS vanish and obtain your Def.2 (of a parametrized geodesic).

Note that parametrized geodesics extremize the **action functional**, whilst unparametrized geodesics extremize the **length functional**, and in the second case $\lambda$ is essentially a Lagrange multiplier.

Comment: Thankyou, I've worked through your solution and made sense of it. For the second derivative of $\alpha$ should there not be a $\frac{d^2 t}{ds^2}$ term, also making its way to the RHS in the result?

Comment: Yes you are right! I will edit